# change mouse out event parameter in onclick

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the html structure like

```
<tr>
<td valign="top">   <div class="thumbnails">  <a id="1" href="#">
<img alt="ebony" rel2="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/ebony1.jpg" onmouseout="swap_image( event, 'http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/ebony1.jpg')" rel1="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/ebony2.jpg" onmouseover="swap_image( event, 'http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/ebony2.jpg')" src="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/ebony1.jpg"></a></div></td>
<td valign="top">   <div class="thumbnails">  <a id="2" href="#" class="selected">
<img alt="iceglass" rel2="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/iceglass1.jpg" onmouseout="swap_image( event, 'http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/iceglass1.jpg')" rel1="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/iceglass2.jpg" onmouseover="swap_image( event, 'http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/iceglass2.jpg')" src="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/iceglass2.jpg"></a></div></td>
<td valign="top">   <div class="thumbnails">  <a id="3" href="#">
<img alt="glimmerglass" rel2="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/glimmerglass1.jpg" onmouseout="swap_image( event, 'http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/glimmerglass1.jpg')" rel1="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/glimmerglass2.jpg" onmouseover="swap_image( event, 'http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/glimmerglass2.jpg')" src="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/glimmerglass1.jpg"></a></div></td>
<td valign="top">   <div class="thumbnails">  <a id="4" href="#">
<img alt="purpleglass" rel2="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/purpleglass1.jpg" onmouseout="swap_image( event, 'http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/purpleglass1.jpg')" rel1="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/purpleglass2.jpg" onmouseover="swap_image( event, 'http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/purpleglass2.jpg')" src="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/purpleglass1.jpg"></a></div></td>
<td valign="top">   <div class="thumbnails">  <a id="5" href="#">
<img alt="shorestone" rel2="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/shorestone1.jpg" onmouseout="swap_image( event, 'http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/shorestone1.jpg')" rel1="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/shorestone2.jpg" onmouseover="swap_image( event, 'http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/shorestone2.jpg')" src="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/shorestone1.jpg"></a></div></td>
<td valign="top">   <div class="thumbnails">  <a id="6" href="#">
<img alt="lavastone" rel2="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/lavastone1.jpg" onmouseout="swap_image( event, 'http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/lavastone1.jpg')" rel1="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/lavastone2.jpg" onmouseover="swap_image( event, 'http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/lavastone2.jpg')" src="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/lavastone1.jpg"></a></div></td>
<td valign="top">   <div class="thumbnails">  <a id="7" href="#">
<img alt="moonstone/dark" rel2="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/moonstone-dark1.jpg" onmouseout="swap_image( event, 'http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/moonstone-dark1.jpg')" rel1="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/moonstone2.jpg" onmouseover="swap_image( event, 'http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/moonstone2.jpg')" src="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/moonstone-dark1.jpg"></a></div></td>
<td valign="top">   <div class="thumbnails">  <a id="8" href="#">
<img alt="moonstone/pale" rel2="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/moonstone-pale1.jpg" onmouseout="swap_image( event, 'http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/moonstone-pale1.jpg')" rel1="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/moonstone-pale2.jpg" onmouseover="swap_image( event, 'http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/moonstone-pale2.jpg')" src="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/moonstone-pale1.jpg"></a></div></td>
<td valign="top">   <div class="thumbnails">  <a id="9" href="#">
<img alt="pebblestone" rel2="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/pebblestone1.jpg" onmouseout="swap_image( event, 'http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/pebblestone1.jpg')" rel1="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/pebblestone2.jpg" onmouseover="swap_image( event, 'http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-mouseover-thumb-images/pebblestone2.jpg')" src="http://localhost/sample/wp-content/gallery/fire-objects-thumb-images/pebblestone1.jpg"></a></div></td>
</tr>
```

and i have added a coding  to change the image on mouse over

```
function swap_image( event, image_url ) {
   var e = event || window.event;
   if( e.target )
     var node = e.target;
   else
     var node = e.srcElement;

   if( node )
     if( node.tagName == "IMG" ){    
      node.src = image_url;

      }
   else{

      node.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = image_url;
      }    
   return false;

}
```

and i want to display the image which is selected for that i want to change the mouseout function parameter.  Every thing is working fine but the mouseout  function param is not changed

```
jQuery(".thumbnails a").live('click' ,function(){

    var selectedclass = jQuery('#portfolio tr td .thumbnails a').hasClass('selected');
    //alert(selectedclass);
    if(selectedclass)
    {
        var small_img = jQuery('#portfolio tr td .thumbnails .selected').find('img').attr('rel2');
        var big_img = jQuery('#portfolio tr td .thumbnails .selected').find('img').attr('rel1');
        jQuery('#portfolio tr td .thumbnails .selected').find('img').attr('src',small_img);
        jQuery('#portfolio tr td .thumbnails .selected').find('img').attr('onmouseover',swap_image( 'event',big_img));
        jQuery('#portfolio tr td .thumbnails .selected').find('img').attr('onmouseout',swap_image( 'event',small_img));
        jQuery('#portfolio tr td .thumbnails .selected').removeClass('selected');
    }


    var img_url = jQuery(this).find('img').attr('rel1');
    jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src',img_url);
    jQuery(this).find('img').bind('onmouseout',swap_image( 'event',img_url));
    jQuery(this).addClass('selected');

    id = jQuery(this).attr("id");               
    jQuery("#large-img img").hide();
    jQuery('#large_'+id).show(); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/ is probably what your looking for

```
$('#outer').mouseout(function() {
   //functions goes here
});
```

outer would be the id of the element that you are tying the event to.

Comment: I already have a mouse out in a tag. I want to change the mouseout function parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(this).find('img').attr('onmouseout',"swap_image( event,'"+org_url+"')");
```

This doesn't work. You can't set javascript events as attributes.

What you want to do is use the "bind" to bind events to the element. So you should rewrite it to :

```
jQuery(this).find('img').bind('onmouseout',function(){
   swap_image(event, org_url);
});
```

(Sorry I'm not in a javascript testable environment right now it might have a minor syntax error. But this will be the basic idea)